# create object with its property values from flat file, need implementation ideas

Tags: c#, string, parsing, .net-3.5

I got a flat file where the data is not delimetered or something else.
The file contains one large string and one row is represented by 180 chars.

Each column value is definied by a length of chars.
I have to create an object for each row, parse the 180 chars and fill
properties of the created object with the parsed values.

How can i solve this problem without permanent using substring or something else?

Maybe some nice solution with Linq?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1 - Super fast but unsafe:**

- Create your class with `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` and all other unmanaged code markings for length. Your strings will be char array but can be exposed as string after loading.
- Read 180 bytes and create a byte array of the same size inside a `fixed` block
- Change pointer to `IntPtr` and use `Marshal.PtrToStructure()` to load an onject of your class

**Solution 2 - Loading logic in the class:**

- Create a constructor in your class that accepts `byte[]` and inside the objects using `Covenrt.Toxxx` or `Encoding.ASCII.ToString()` assuming it is ASCII
- Read 180 bytes and create an object and pass it to .ctor
- If you have to serialise back to `byte[]` then implement a ToByteArray() method and again use `Covenrt.Toxxx` or `Encoding.ASCII.ToString()` to write to byte.

**Enhancement to solutions 2:**

Create custom attributes and decorate your classes with those so that you can have a factory that reads metadata and inflates your objects using byte array for you. This is most useful if you have more than a couple of such classes.

**Alternative to solutions 2:**

You may pass stream instead of a byte array which is faster. Here you would use BinaryReader and BinaryWriter to read and write values. Strings however is a bit trick since it writes the length as well I think.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [StringReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.aspx) to parse your text, then you won't have to use substring. Linq won't help you here.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with OJ but even with StringReader you will still need the position of each individual value to parse it out of the string...there is nothing wrong with substring just make sure you use static constants when defining the begging and ending lengths.  Example:

```
private static int VAR_START_INDEX = 0;
private static int VAR_END_INDEX = 4;

String data = "thisisthedata";

String var = data.Substring(VAR_START_INDEX,VAR_END_INDEX);
//var would then be equal to 'this'
```

Comment: VAR_END_INDEX should really be called VAR_LENGTH

Answer (score 0):

This library can help you http://f2enum.codeplex.com/